# Склонение названий государств

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Как склоняются названия государств: *Республика Колумбия, Республика Бразилия*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Разные справочники дают разные рекомендации. К примеру, Розенталь советует склонять только названия на *-ия*, *-ея*. Но вот в Словаре географических названий отмечается, что названия со словом *республика* обычно склоняются, если они женского рода.

Таким образом, возможны: Республики Колумб**ии** и Республики Колумб**ия**, Республике Бразил**ии** и Республике Бразил**ия**.

Answer (score 1):

Посольство Республики Корея,  Посольство Федеративной Республики Бразилии, Посольство Республики Колумбии.

При склонении названий государств **они должны не искажаться, должны быть узнаваемыми**. Сохранение точности - это главный критерий при решении о согласовании родового слова с географическим названием.

Поэтому, **по Розенталю,** обычно склоняются названия ж.р. на -ИЯ и не склоняются названия м.р., например: Посольство Республики Судан.