# Падежное согласование названия страны

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Как правильно написать: "Песни страны Гринландия" или "Песни страны Гринландии"?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: Склонение названий государств (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426491/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Мне кажется, что заголовок может быть таким: _Страна Гринландия - склонение._  Метку "топонимика" надо бы поменять на "топонимы" (сама править не решаюсь).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Согласен, так будет лучше. Что Вас удерживает от внесения изменений?

Comment: Субординацию соблюдаю. Лучше даже так: _Страна Гринландия. Склонение литературного топонима._ В одном заголовке - все характеристики.

Answer (score 1):

Особенность этого случая в том, что название страны дано вместе с родовым словом "страна". Думаю, для таких конструкций нет однозначного ответа. Можно почитать здесь: [Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

Вторая особенность: Гринла́ндия — вымышленная страна из произведений Александра Грина (не путать с Гренландией).

Использование названий в их оригинальной форме характерно для военных, а также в других случаях, когда важно соблюсти точность в передаче названий. Учитывая поэтический характер текста, я бы предпочел название склонять: **Песни страны Гринландии**.

> летний конкурс "Песни страны Гринландии" (https://regnum.ru/news/92133.html)